# F# Finding distinct elements in list of tuples

Tags: f#

I have a list of tuples:

```
(string * (int * int)) list
let st = [("a1",(100,10)); ("a2",(50,20)); ("a3",(25,40))]
```

Where I want to make a function which returns a bool on a few conditions: Both the ints have to be more than 0 and the strings in the list have to be distinct.

So far I have:

```
let rec inv st = List.forall (fun (a,(n,p)) -> n>0 && p>0) st
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out how to find out if all the strings in the list are distinct. Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `distinctBy`:

```
let inv st =        
    List.length (List.distinctBy fst st) = List.length st && List.forall (fun (a,(n,p)) -> n>0 && p>0) st
```

or you can combine both checks in a single pipeline:

```
let inv st =        
    st
    |> List.filter (fun (_,(n,p)) -> n>0 && p>0)
    |> List.distinctBy fst
    |> List.length
    |> (=) (List.length st)
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way would be to just compile the list of all distinct strings (via `List.distinct`) and see if it ended up the same size as the original list:

```
let allDistinctStirngs = st |> List.map fst |> List.distinct
let allStringsAreDistinct = List.length st = List.length allDistinctStrings
```